# Android Studio : Get Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, google-api, google-play

I want to use Google Maps in my app

But when I run my app I get this error

> This app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone. GET GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES

I tried other solutions like installing the google api from SDK Manager but did not work, and still get the same error.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you use an emulator ?

Comment: your device needs these services, they are not part of your app. are you running on a device or an emulator?

Comment: `Google Play services, which are missing from your phone.` You need to [install google play services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) in your phone

Comment: Here a guide ton install gapps which contains google play services : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: I use emulator, How to install the google play services. when I click the button nothing happens

Comment: There is no Google Play icon in the apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run application that uses Google Play Services, your emulator or device must have Google Play Services installed.

In Android SDK Manager allows you to install emulator system images with preinstalled Google Play Services.

[image: SDK Manager Google API isystem images]

When you have those installed on your system, you can then create emulator that will be able to run your application.

Open AVD Manager and create new emulator. Make sure that you use some of Google API system images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your device/emulator **don't have gapps isntalled.**

**Google Play Services** is coming with Google apps (called gapps). A great tutorial can be found here : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

By the way, use CM11 gapps link.