# Android - this app won't run without google play services which are missing from your phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-api, google-play-services, google-api-client

This is the message in my emulator when I try to run my app:

> this app won't run without google play services which are missing from
>   your phone.

What does it mean and what can I do to solve it ?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105558/this-app-wont-run-without-google-play-services-which-are-missing-from-your-phone   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140283/android-studio-get-google-play-services   These will provide answer

Comment: @androidjava: where have you reached with this ?